# handlebars.net on iOS in xamarin not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, handlebars.net

is handlebars.net working on iOS for anybody? I can't make it running. On Android all work fine.

When debugging it looks like .compile() of Expression is ok and debug of Expression string is the same as on android, but when lambda is called nothing happens and my json is not applied.

I was trying to write my own simple expressions and they are working, but they are probably resolved in advance in static manner...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Handlebars templates are compled to IL dynamically which is allowed, but execution of that IL is not allowed on iOS.

Comment: It is strange that I was trying to write my own 'dynamic' expression with if a and Rand() to generate every time something different and it was working. So I expect my Expression was AOT  in advance or it is caused by something else too. Does not Handlebars use Dynamic object too? Anyway, if you rewrite your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Beware that the iOS simulator does not enforce the code execution restriction, physical devices running release builds will. Now reflection is totally allowed, but memory JIT/executionis forbidden. Apple Store App's like Frank Krueger's Continuous (C#/F# editor|compiler|execution) on iOS use a combination of a IL interpreter and reflection to "execute" the Rosyln generated code. (Frank custom wrote the IL interpreter so it "looks" like it is executing IL (JIT'ing) what was compiled into a memory stream, but it is actually doing IL interpretation). Android has no such restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as iOS doesn't support code generation, it won't be able to support Handlebars.Net.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/#No_Dynamic_Code_Generation